# How to add pagination in Restangular and Django Rest Framework?

Tags: angularjs, django, pagination, django-rest-framework, restangular

In DRF I have added pagination limit to 100 `'PAGINATE_BY': 100,`
since Restangular expects results in array form, I had to use the below meta extractor function in my angular app module

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", ["restangular"].config(function(
            RestangularProvider){

  RestangularProvider.setResponseExtractor(function(response, operation, what, url) {
    if (operation === "getList") {
        var newResponse = response.results;
        newResponse._resultmeta = {
            "count": response.count,
            "next": response.next,
            "previous": response.previous
        };
        return newResponse;
    }

    return response;
    });
});
```

and my controller looks like

```
app.controller('DataCtrl',function($scope, Restangular){

    var resource = Restangular.all('myapp/api/dataendpoint/');
        resource.getList().then(function(data){
        $scope.records = data;
    });    
}
```

Meta info is not available in controller, how do I paginate if there are more than 100 records available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could simply call:

```
RestangularProvider.addResponseExtractor(function(data, operation, what, url, response) {
  if (operation === "getList") {
      data._resultmeta = {
          "count": response.count,
          "next": response.next,
          "previous": response.previous
      };
      return data;
  }

  return response;
});
```

and

```
var page = 2;
var resource = Restangular.all('myapp/api/dataendpoint/');
resource.getList({page: page}).then(function(data){
  console.log(data._resultmeta.next ? 'there is more pages' : 'You reach the end');
});
```

I'm not usual with `Rectangular` but [Django Rest Framework support pagination from query parameter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagenumberpagination)

Comment: for latest version of restangular use addResponseInterceptor() instead of addResponseExtractor()